# How to list missing numerical values using SQL

Tags: sql

i'm trying to figure out an SQL request for the API i'm developping.

So we have this "Paddle" table where the user registers and the api must provide a possible number for the paddle (simply a functionnal ID). Considering that the user can specify his own paddle number, i need to create a request that picks up every missing value.

I already have an sql request for that :

```
select MIN(p.number)+1 FROM Paddle p WHERE not exists(
SELECT pa.number
FROM Paddle pa
WHERE pa.channel = 'ABSENTEE'
      AND pa.sale_id = 3
      AND p.number + 1 = pa.number) AND p.channel = 'ABSENTEE' AND p.sale_id = 3);
```

But it can't detect when there is no paddle number 1.

The channel and sale_id are to restrict the numbers (i can have two paddle with 1 as number but not for the same sale and channel)

So i would like to add a part to the request where if there is no paddle number one, the number is added to the result set of the sub request.

Thanks for the replies !

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. 
    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something like that:

```
select pid from
(
    select 1 as pid
    union all
    select p.number+1 from Paddle
) as q
where
pid not in (select p.number from Paddle)
```

so, in sub-query `q` I'm getting all IDs which are probably empty and then filter out used ones

Comment: I just tested your solution, it works perfectly, thanks !